# UILocalNotification issue with past dates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am making a reminder app, if there aren't a million out there.

- I let the user specify a time to remind him of a to-do task.
- So lets say the user specifies that he needs to be reminded at 9:00am every Monday.
- When he closes the app and its goes in the background I create a UILocalNotification fire time.
- at 9:00am on next Monday the user gets the notification.
- If he launches my app and adds another reminder for some other day/time (not important) and closes my app by clicking on the home button then he gets a notification right away.
- This is because the first notification was set to past Monday date

How can I avoid this yet still deliver a notification next monday?

I found this by googling
"If you specify a date that is in the past (or nil) the notification is delivered immediately. "

Comment: To answer my own question, I cannot do this the way I have designed it. I can create local notification at the time the new reminder is created. I cannot do this in applicationDidEnterBackground

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I got from your question:

- User makes repeating *event* for **9:00AM** every **Monday**
- You schedule a single local notification for the next occurring **Monday at 9:00AM**
- One **Monday at 9:00AM** occurs; the users's *event* fires
- User makes another arbitrary event
- The users's first *event* fires, as if it was **Monday at 9:00AM**, presumably because **Monday at 9:00AM** has already happened once

In order to resolve this, you want to make sure you're doing both of these things:

1. Make sure you're releasing the `UILocalNotification`.

   ```
   //Manual Memory Management
   [yourLocalNotif release];

   //Automatic Reference Counting
   yourLocalNotif = nil;
   ```
2. Make sure rescheduling your repeating events for the next occurring time.

If this isn't quite what you're looking for, post some code and I'll try and reevaluate :)